# Ajax - Image uploads

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I replace this code 1 with code 2, is it still same or not for the action?

Code 1

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var thumb = $('img#thumb');        

  new AjaxUpload('imageUpload', {
    action: $('form#newHotnessForm').attr('action'),
    name: 'image',
    onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
      $('div.preview').addClass('loading');
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response) {
      thumb.load(function(){
        $('div.preview').removeClass('loading');
        thumb.unbind();
      });
      thumb.attr('src', response);
    }
  });
  
});
```

Code 2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
      var thumb = $('img#thumb');        
    
      new AjaxUpload('imageUpload', {
        action: 'upload.php',
        name: 'image',
        onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
          $('div.preview').addClass('loading');
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response) {
          thumb.load(function(){
            $('div.preview').removeClass('loading');
            thumb.unbind();
          });
          thumb.attr('src', response);
        }
      });
      
    });
```

Comment: do `console.log( $('form#newHotnessForm').attr('action') == 'upload.php')` Not sure what you are trying to do.. but if you know that the action should always be 'upload.php' (which is probably what you want) then why query the dom for that?

Comment: yes its the same... it selects the action of the form. having issues with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the same, if `$('form#newHotnessForm').attr('action')` is equal to `'upload.php'`.